# Unable to start RabbitMq Service after uninstalling and then Re-installing RabbitMQ

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, erlang

I uninstalled rabbitMq using this guide: https://support.bioconnect.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011178868-How-to-Uninstall-RabbitMQ

1. uninstalled RabbitMq and Erlang
2. ended empd.exe in task manager
3. deleted the directories for rabbitMQ and erlang
4. deleted HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Ericsson from 'regedit'
5. removed the service from services
6. I also deleted the C:\Windows.erlang.cookie and C:\Users[username]/.erlang.cookie.

After I tried reinstalling using this other guide: https://cmatskas.com/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-windows/

1. installed Erlang
2. downloaded and installed rabbitMQ
3. Navigate to the sbin directory of the RabbitMQ Server installation directory. 'C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.3.4\sbin'
   and ran 'rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management'

I navigated to http://localhost:15672/ and the site was unreachable. I opened up services to make sure that the rabbitMq service was on and it was not even created. I tried running the command 'rabbitmq-service install' as admin and got the following back

`RabbitMQ service is already present - only updating service parameters
C:\Program Files\erl9.2\erts-9.2\bin\erlsrv: Warning, could not set correct interactive mode. RabbitMQ
Error: The handle is invalid.
C:\Program Files\erl9.2\erts-9.2\bin\erlsrv: Warning, could not set correct service description (comment) RabbitMQError: The handle is invalid.`

I am wondering if i missed a step somewhere. Cant get rabbit to work.

Answer (score 39):

I also ran into this problem recently.

These simple steps solved the issue for me:

- Open Regedit.exe
- Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang\ErlSrv\1.1\RabbitMQ
- Remove that key

Now running `rabbitmq-service.bat install` is successful.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the service and reinstall it using the following steps:

1. Open CMD as administrator and navigate to the sbin folder (Mine is `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.4\sbin`)
2. Remove RabbitMQ service by:

   `rabbitmq-service.bat remove`
3. Reinstall it by:

   `rabbitmq-service.bat install`
4. Start the service by:

   `rabbimq-service.bat start`

Comment: To clear the installation state for RabbitMQ you need to delete registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang\ErlSrv\1.1\RabbitMQ